# getting elements in DOM in d3

Tags: dom, get, d3.js, element

My code looks like this. I wrote this with the help of the d3js website, because I am learning how to use d3. it is my first JS library so the syntax and customs were a little confusing at first but I think I got it down.

This code creates a bar chart. You'll notice that in the CSS I made the text display = none, and I only want it to display when someone moves their mouse over the bar chart. My plan was to get all the text elements by getElementsByClassName, and I also tried GetElementsByTagName and passed it "text", but that didn't work either. Once I have a handle to these elements I can create an event listener to talk to them. but I don't know how to create said handle.

```
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js" charset="UTF-8"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .chart rect {
            fill: steelblue;
            stroke: white;
        }
        .chart text {
            font-family:"Courier New", Courier, monospace;
            fill:white;
            display:none;
        }
        .chart rect:hover {
            fill:red;
            stroke:white;
        }
    </style>
</head> 
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = [43, 12, 49, 32, 33, 41, 56, 67, 75, 89, 91, 100];
        var chart = d3.select("body").append("svg")
            .attr("class", "chart")
            .attr("width", 420)
            .attr("height", 20 * data.length);
        var x = d3.scale.linear()
            .domain([0,d3.max(data)])
            .range([0,420]);
        var y = d3.scale.ordinal()
                .domain(data)
                .rangeBands([0, 20*data.length]);

        chart.selectAll("rect").data(data)
            .enter().append("rect")
            .attr("y", y)
            .attr("width", x)
            .attr("height", y.rangeBand());
        chart.selectAll("text").data(data)
            .enter().append("text")
            .attr("class", "textClass")
            .attr("x", x)
            .attr("y", function(d){return y(d) +y.rangeBand()/2;})
            .attr("dx", -3) // padding-right
            .attr("dy", ".35em") // vertical-align: middle
            .attr("text-anchor", "end") // text-align: right
            .text(String);
        textElements = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");
            console.log(textElements);
    </script>
</body>
```

I am most interested in these two lines:

```
        textElements = document.getElementsByClassName("textClass");
            console.log(textElements);
```

and why am I not getting a console.log message in firebug giving me the array? It is coming back as undefined.

Comment: You can also use d3 to select the elements: `textElements = chart.selectAll('.textClass');`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works with JQuery when you put your JavaScript within a `$(function() { ... });` block.

See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/CELxx/3/

Comment: A fiddle is worth a thousand tuts. Thanks.